# Write an integral giving the amount of work required to empty the full tank of fuel to a height 2 feet above the top of the tank

Tags: calculus

The tank shown below is in the shape of a right triangular prism where cross sections
parallel to the ground are rectangles (2 ft by 4 ft) and cross sections parallel to the front
face are right triangles (6ft tall and 2 ft wide at the top). The tank is initially filled to
the top with a fuel whose weight-density is 80 lb/ft3. The fuel is to be pumped out of the
tank to a height 2 feet above the top of the tank. Write an integral giving the amount of
work required to empty the full tank of fuel to a height 2 feet above the top of the tank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we must know the work formula, which is F times d.

In order to find the work done here, we are trying to integrate F with respect with d.

I'm not sure what you mean by the cross sections being 2 by 4 feet, since the cross sections will vary in length in width as you go up in height. Same idea goes for the right triangle's cross sections.

Please either clarify your answer or provide a photo of some sort to aid understanding.